# Java - Как можно сгруппировать элементы одного активити

Tags: java, android

Как можно сгруппировать элементы одного активити?
Необходимо для того, чтобы выставлять сразу нескольким элементам одно свойство, в данном случае мне необходимо при определенном условии оба элемента сделать неактивными (невидимые + не занимают места):

```
    nameTextEdit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    nameText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Этот код для каждого в отдельности выставляет свойство, а мне необходимо сделать один атрибут видимости на группу элементов.

Comment: Если они лежат в одном контейнере и в нём кроме них ничего не лежит - скрывайте контейнер. Иначе - добавьте ссылки на вьюхи в список и циклом по нему бегайте и скрывайте

Comment: Нашёл ответ в том, чтобы сгруппировать в layout.

Answer (score 1):

EditText - наследник класса TextView.
Слабая типизация в Java позволяет сделать что-то вроде

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
```

и использовать метод .setVisibility родительского класса. 
Так что получайте ссылки на ваши объекты, приведением присваивая предку, засовывайте на ходу их в ArrayList и в цикле выполняйте нужные вам действия. Главное не злоупотреблять этим приёмом - ошибки при путанице с типами тяжело отлавливать.

Comment: а зачем приводить к TextView?

Comment: Согласен, можно сразу получать View, если вопрос только в том, чтобы скрыть/показать View'ы

Comment: `EditText` вообще не надо ни к чему приводить. Если вы внимательно посмотрите вопрос, то увидите, что ссылки на него уже получены и со скрытием проблем нет, есть проблема с групповым скрытием. Вот я и спрашиваю, как решит проблему группового скрытия приведение вверх по иерархии к чему бы то ни было, почему нельзя в `ArrayList` складывать уже полученные ссылки на `EditText`, а нужно непременно получить новые из иерархии выше и потом предупреждать, что это может привести к проблемам?